# Bubble sort tiny error

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make my program sort this array of numbers from least to greatest but the output is coming out otherwise. In other words, I'm trying to not use a[4] because that's what this algorithm is doing but I can't figure out how.  Thanks for reading.

Output:
9 12 3 14

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int a[4] = {12, 9, 14, 3};
    int temp;

    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        if(a[i] > a[i + 1]) {
            temp = a[i];
            a[i] = a[i + 1];
            a[i + 1] = temp;
        }
        cout << a[i] << " ";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: a[3+1] is out of bounds ....  Stop at a[2 + 1]

Comment: Make a tiny adjustment in your for loop to address what T33C said,something like `for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)`, after that the output you are getting is correct for the given code.

Comment: @bkVnet Nope! http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5bcd33c4f3d5fa4c

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ OK, i meant the result of the sorted array. I guess i made a tiny error myself :)

Comment: i < 3 doesn't work.  I tried everything but I can't figure it out.  I've been on this thing the entire day & I can't find the missing piece to this once and for all.  I need to know how to stop at a[2 + 1].

Comment: @reppo -  A bubble sort requires two loops, not one.  Look at the algorithm closely from a book or whatever you're using, and then look at your code.  Does your code mimic what the algorithm does?

Answer (score 1):

You have three errors:

**Error 1:**  **An out-of-bounds access during the loop.**

This:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
```

should be

```
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
```

The reason being is that if you use the first (wrong) version, you have a buffer overrun:

```
    if(a[i] > a[i + 1])  // if i == 3, a[3+1] == a[4] == out-of-bounds
```

---

**Error 2:  Writing the output while sorting.**

You're doing this:

```
    cout << a[i] << " ";
```

in the middle of the sort.  It makes no sense to print out the values of the array if the sort has not been completed.

This should be placed outside the sorting code (once the sorting has completed):

```
 for ( int i = 0; i < 4; ++i)
    cout << a[i] << " ";
```

---

**Error 3:  Incorrect implementation of bubble sort.**

A bubble sort works by making multiple passes through the data until it is detected that the data is sorted.  Your code only makes one pass through the data and then exits.

What you need to do is have a `while` or similar loop that has within it, the `for` loop.  The `while` loop only gets executed if the data requires at least one more pass through the data.  You will know when the data is sorted if the `if` condition in the `for` loop never executes (meaning no swaps occurred, thus the data is sorted).

Here is an example:

```
int temp;
bool is_sorted = false;
while ( !is_sorted )  // execute while data is not sorted
{
    isSorted = true;  // assume data is sorted
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
       if(a[i] > a[i + 1])
       {
          //.. swap the items
          //...
          isSorted = false;  // swap made, so data was not sorted
       }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There is already a header file called "algorithm" with which you can do that:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

typedef pair<char, int> new_pair;

struct sorting{
       bool operator() (int i, int j){return i < j;}
}test_sort;

int main(void){
        int test[4] = {5, 2, 1, 10};
        sort(test, test + 3, test_sort);
        for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){
                cout <<test[i] << endl;
        }
        return 0;
}
```

I wish I helped you.